# Sound and new images fail to load in View after my app runs for about 30 minutes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a game, that at first seem too run fine, but.......
after it runs a long time the sound first stops to work, 
[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]; returns a null and a little while later when I try to set a view equal to a new image, by view.image=, I get a error in my console that says to many files open,
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/deno/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/5A0C777C-70D1-4AA0-8D7B-04A1F734C932/cPetCakes.app/twinkles04fin32.png'
         error = 24 (Too many open files)

right now I creat a new I'm creating a new AVAudioPlayer object each time a sound is played. Should I be re-using the object or some how freeing it??? Since I was not using a alloc, I was thinking that the object would be freed automatcly???

Code for sound

```
-(void) PlaySound: (NSString *) name
{
    NSURL *url;

    if ( [name compare:@"chasdog"]==0)
        url  = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       URLForResource:name
                       withExtension:@"wav"];

        else
    url  = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
             URLForResource:name
             withExtension:@"mp3"];

    NSError *error;

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops= 0;
    [audioPlayer play];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;    

}
```

code that no longer loads in new images

```
 self.image=gPetCakeB[gGame->mPetCakeId];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the player delegate it's needed to release the player once it's stopped playing:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [player release];
}
```